# Was it some kind of charm spell that affected Elayne and Nynaeve while meeting Moghedien?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

In Shadow Rising, Chp 46, Elayne and Nynaeve were really excited and acted like they were under some kind of charm spell when Moghedien came. What kind of spell was that? It seems really easy for the Forsaken.

Comment: Yes, it was some charm spell. As I recall, it is explained later on, and they learn to cast the spell themselves. It's been 10 years since I read the books, however. :)

Comment: I this is the first time I've seen channelling referred to as a *spell*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was Compulsion.  There are many examples later in the series of the Forsaken using it, and even some of the good guys.  Graendal and Ishamael use it a lot.

Comment: Liandrin & her pals too use it in book 3 on Juilin Sandar.

Comment: @jv42 are you sure?

Comment: Yes I just reread books 3&4, and it's very clear.

Comment: Yeah, but Liandrin had only weakest version not true Compulsion, which was banned by Tower and considered lost. Moghedien had a real deal and Graendel was strongest with this.

Answer (score 2):

The weave is called Compulsion. However, it would be inaccurate to call Compulsion a "charm spell". It's actually much closer to hypnosis. In and of itself, it doesn't influence the subject's disposition all that much, other than to induce a willingness to co-operate. As you will notice in the passage in question, the girls were unquestioningly obedient, but didn't become enamoured with there interrogator until *instructed* to feel that way.

Comment: No downvote since this is from 2013, but much of this answer is wrong. Compulsion at its lowest levels induces cooperation. At the higher levels, though, it's definitely closer to what we'd call a charm spell. In fact, at its highest uses, it will turn a hostile, aggressive enemy into a fawning love minion who thinks you're the best thing since sliced bread.